# Foundation 5 - How to pull down middle section of the grid

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation

How do i pull down the middle section below?

Here is image what i am trying to do.

[image]

Comment: This is not ideal, but you could duplicate your content and use the `show-for-small-only` and `show-for-medium-up`. There's probably a better way, but that would work  . . . technically. Also look into the source ordering features perhaps? http://zurb.com/word/source-order

Comment: @CollinD Yes, I am reading source ordering. Push and Pull does something better.

Comment: push and pull doesn't work as expected. Looked source code and understood the reason. If you **pull** it gives **right** to **%x**, vice versa for **push**. So it doesn't _collapse_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if you change the order of your html, you can push and pull in your `large` view, and then it will correct itself when switching to medium. See my pen:

http://codepen.io/lcarter/pen/ZbrMYb

Comment: I tried doing this but wasn't successful. Yours is looking good. I am trying now.

Comment: I did the same thing yesterday didn't work, now it is working. Thanks.

Comment: I found my problem. I was giving extra margins to the columns which i shouldn't. I am new to foundation.